# Converting the names of a list elements as a variable in a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, dplyr

I have a named `List` of data.frames. I was wondering how to convert the name (`"bar1"`,...,`"bar4"`) of each element `List` as a column next to each data.frame?

My final `desired_output` is shown below.

```
List <- list(bar1=data.frame(study="A",sd = 1), bar2=data.frame(study=c("B","C"),sd=2:3),
     bar3=data.frame(study="Z",sd = 4), bar4=data.frame(study="H",sd=5))

# desired_output:
"
  study sd   id
      A  1 bar1
      B  2 bar2
      C  3 bar2
      Z  4 bar3
      H  5 bar4
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I think of iterating over a vector I think of the `map` functions in `purrr`. In this case, `map2()` iterates over multiple arguments simultaneously. I grabbed the names of the list elements and stored them in a vector, `n`:

```r
n <- names(List)
```

I then iterated over `List` and `n` at the same time, calling `cbind()` to add a variable (i.e., column) to each data frame:

```r
map2(List, n, ~ cbind(.x, Name = .y))
```

**Output:**

```
$bar1
  study sd Name
1     A  1 bar1

$bar2
  study sd Name
1     B  2 bar2
2     C  3 bar2

$bar3
  study sd Name
1     Z  4 bar3

$bar4
  study sd Name
1     H  5 bar4
```

We can collapse `List` to a single data frame with a call to `bind_rows()`:

```r
result <- map2(List, n, ~ cbind(.x, Name = .y))
bind_rows(result)
```

**Output:**

```
  study sd Name
1     A  1 bar1
2     B  2 bar2
3     C  3 bar2
4     Z  4 bar3
5     H  5 bar4
```

Taken as one statement that would be:

```r
map2(List, names(List), ~ cbind(.x, Name = .y)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Or you could simply use `map2_dfr` instead of `map2`.

Comment: You don't really need the `map` here, `bind_rows` can do all this for you: `bind_rows(List, .id="id")`

Answer (score 4):

The `dplyr::bind_rows` function has an `.id=` parameter that you can use to create a column with the names from the list of data.frames you pass in. You can just do

```
bind_rows(List, .id="id")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `Map`:

```
do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, id = names(List), List)))
```

**Output**

```
    id study sd
1 bar1     A  1
2 bar2     B  2
3 bar2     C  3
4 bar3     Z  4
5 bar4     H  5
```

Another option is to use `rbindlist` from `data.table`:

```
rbindlist(List, idcol = "id")

#     id study sd
#1: bar1     A  1
#2: bar2     B  2
#3: bar2     C  3
#4: bar3     Z  4
#5: bar4     H  5
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
data.frame(do.call(rbind, List),
           id = rep.int(names(List), vapply(List, nrow, 0L)),
           row.names = NULL)
##   study sd   id
## 1     A  1 bar1
## 2     B  2 bar2
## 3     C  3 bar2
## 4     Z  4 bar3
## 5     H  5 bar4
```